# Import data into sql server from files with different format

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a program, which watches a folder on the server. when new files (flat file) come in, the program (C#) read data, bulk insert into the table. it works fine.

Now, we extend the system. It means the data files could be in different formats (flat file, csv, txt, excel..), or with different columns (we need map them to the columns in the table).

my question is: is C# the best choice for this? or, SSIS is a better choice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn’t necessarily choose one or the other but choose depending on the file type and the amount of processing. For some file types its probably easier to go with C# and for some other SSIS works better.

Do you have someone on your team who is good with SSIS? It’s much easier to find a C# dev to do the job for you than to find someone who knows SSIS.

How likely is that requirements/formats are going to be updated in the future? That’s also important thing to keep in mind.

I do agree with what others said that SSIS is more powerful and offers support for more complex transformations but the questions is do you really need this?

Answer (score 2):

It's depends on your context. Different format should not decision go to SSIS. With solution C# program: you can continue go with it because it run stable before. Easy to deployment, specific into your domain, easy to configuration as well.
With solution SSIS: The configuration more complicate required developer has deep knowledge into SSIS. The administration fee required more than C# program. However it easy to visual (has diagram for you see the flow integration more easier). 
From my viewpoint, if the integration process does not required complicated about business rule you should go with C# program. Otherwise, SSIS more powerful if integration process  required rules complicated. Hope this help.

Comment: one thing I have concern is: it needs to keep watching a folder for new files coming. Right now, it uses windows service and works fine. If use SSIS, will I have to use SQL agent to call the SSIS to do the similar thing?

Comment: SSIS has provide a file watching task which are similar you done with your C# program watching folder. You can take reference here: http://www.sqlis.com/post/file-watcher-task.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In C# application I guess you are using the SqlbulkCopy component and compared to SSIS its not that powerful. So if your data size becomes huge,then C# application will become slower.

If you are familiar with SSIS,my suggestion is to go with SSIS. In SSIS,you can implement end-to-end solution as you have developed in C#,right from checking the files in a specific folder to loading the data into database.